# Determine the maximum count of substrings that can be formed by cutting maximum length substring with at most K distinct characters from the starting

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

You are given a string S of length N consisting of lowercase English alphabets and an integer K. You need to partition the string until it is empty in the following way,

Select a maximum length substring from the beginning of string S such that it has at most K distinct characters.

Delete the selected substring in step-1 from string S.

You are allowed to change at most 1 character.

Determine the maximum count of substrings that can be formed until the string S becomes empty.

Example:

Assumptions

- N = 7
- K = 3
- S = abcccba

Approach

Without changing any character in string S.

For string S = abcccba.

- The selected substring is "abcccba". On deleting the substring, the string S = ""(an empty string).

On changing S[3] with character 'z'.

For string S = abczcba.

- The selected substring is "abc". On deleting the substring the string S = zcba.
  For string S = zcba.
- The selected substring is "zcb". On deleting the substring the string S = a.
  For string S = a.
- The selected substring is "a". On deleting the substring the string S = "" (an empty string).
  Thus the answer is 3. Therefore the answer is 3.

We can do it as follow with a brute force approach which is not optimised

```py
def calculate_count(s, k): 
    a = 0 
    st = set()
    z = 0

    i = 0
    while i < len(s): 
        while i < len(s) and z < k:
            if s[i] not in st:
                z += 1
                st.add(s[i])
            i += 1
        st.clear()
        z = 0
        a += 1
    return a

def solve(N, K, S):
    ans = -1
    S = list(S)
    for i in range(N):
        ch = S[i] 
        curr = calculate_count(S, K) 
        S[i] = '#' 
        curr1 = calculate_count(S, K) 
        S[i] = ch
        ans = max(curr, ans, curr1)
    return ans
```

It looks like we can use dynamic programming to solve that optimally, But how can we do that?

Comment: Please check [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and let us know what you have already tried.

Comment: Thanks for that, I added my brute force approach, which does not look optimal,

Comment: Your brute force attempt is not clear. What is your implementation of `calculate_count`?

Comment: @trincot added the brute force code

Comment: @trincot I think he look for the ** maximum count  ** of subtrings, not the min

Comment: I'm pretty sure your solution have some problems even with the brute force... try to input "bbaaaa" with k = 2 and you'll get 3 even so there's no solution with count of 3 in any change of char

Comment: Does the change have to be to a lowercase ascii letter? In your attempt you change to something outside of the alphabet, which could be an issue for any string `S` of length larger than 26 (number of lowercase ascii letters) containing all ascii lowercase letters.